nested switch statements for template arguments
We have some templated function that takes 2 compile-time arguments, e.g.
template<int a, int b> 
void SomeFunc(double *x, double *y, double *z);

For performance reasons, it is better to have specialized implementations of this function based on some predefined set of values for a and b. A reasonable number of values for each is 10, thus a total of 100 implementations of SomeFunc at most are possible. If you are wondering why, it's because for the application considered, knowing those values at compile-time allows the compiler to better optimize SomeFunc, particularly since it involves heavy dense computations.
One way around this is to have 2 nested switch statements and evaluate this at runtime, each time the function gets called. However, this is both redundant as well as needlessly re-evaluating the same switch statements each time (since the values a and b do not change).
Another approach could be to have a function pointer that preprocesses the values of a and b and decides which function to point to. In this case, SomeFunc is relatively big enough, such that I do not have to worry about inlining it and so I wouldn't have to pay for performance costs here. Still, the problem is that we would have to write those 2 tedious nested switch statements, e.g.
auto DecideFuncPtr(int A, int B)
{
  switch(A)
  {
    case(1): return fa1(B);
    case(2): return fa2(B);
    ...
  }
}

with each specialized implementation looking like:
// A = 1
auto fa1(int B)
{
  switch(B)
  {
    case(1): return SomeFunc<1,1>;
    case(2): return SomeFunc<1,2>;
    ...
  }
}

// A = 2
auto fa2(int B)
{
  switch(B)
  {
    case(1): return SomeFunc<2,1>;
    case(2): return SomeFunc<2,2>;
    ...
  }
}
...

And finally, preprocessing the relevant function once (e.g. in a constructor) as such:
auto f = DecideFuncPtr(A, B);

// Use the function later on as such:
f(matrix_A, matrix_B, matrix_C);

Thus, you can see how messy this can look like in terms of design. Specifically, if one needs to add/adjust the combination of implementable values a and b. Is there any way to make this slightly nicer, while still ensuring that the resulting function SomeFunc has values a and b known at compile-time?
For completion, I can use C++17 or even C++20.

EDIT: I forgot to add the function type (void); not that changes the pseudo-code and question posed. Also, note that the values of a and b are not necessarily sequential. Here I specify values of 1 and 2 for demonstration purposes only..

"Is there any way to make this slightly nicer..." Nicer means different things to different people. Define what do you mean by "nicer" in programming language c++. So Opinion based. Just like "Wonderful people on SO..." isn't necessarily nice. It could be considered sarcasm by some. And tbh being an experienced user of SO, I would consider it sarcasm.

For performance reasons, it is better to have specialized implementations of this function based on some predefined set of values for a and b. My experience is: if that is true, chances are your compiler might already be doing this. Verify whether a templated function is really faster. You might be saving yourself a lot of work.

This looks like micro-optimization specially the time and effort one has to put in handling all 10 implementations correctly.

You could replace all the auto faXX(int B) functions by a template function template <int A> auto fa<A>(int B), with all the returns changed to return SomeFunc<A, number from switch>;

@user12002570 don't assume sarcasm by default. That way lies pain when dealing with strangers! But what "Wonderful people on SO" definitely is is a distraction with no relation to the question – and you're allowed to improve questions ;)

@MarcusMüller I have verified it is faster. To be specific, the internal computations using OpenMP SIMD intrinsics are indeed faster, once the values are known at compile time. I have benchmarked this time and time again.

@debronee101 thanks! yeah, with hand-optimized SIMD, this can be the case (see libvolk.org, which I'm mildly involved in).

You could use std::make_index_sequence to generate a range (0..max_A * max_B), construct an array of function pointers of the form SomeFunc<N/max_B,N%max_B> and finally index that array at runtime using a * max_b + b?

One thing I wonder about: where do the a and b come from, at runtime? Could you illustrate how it would look like where you use the function?

@MarcusMüller a and b are essentially particular matrix dimensions. These come from the user, which depends on the application considered. Should I add that information in the answer or you think it suffices to assume this implicitly?

@user12002570 You're not exactly wrong in saying it's micro-optimization. Yet, since SomeFunc is called repetitively and internally uses SIMD intrinsics (vectorization), you do gain a sizeable performance when you do these sort of optimizations. The compile-time arguments, padding, alignment, etc. It sure is ugly, but you only have to implement it once.

One way to turn runtime value to compile time value is to use std::variant:
std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value0>,
    std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value1>,
    std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value2>
    // ...
> to_variant(enumA a) {
    switch (a) {
        case enumA::Value0: return std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value0>{};
        case enumA::Value1: return std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value1>{};
        case enumA::Value2: return std::integral_constant<enumA, enumA::Value2>{};
// ...
    }
    std::unreachable(); // Or throw
}

// Similar for enumB

You do it once by type. you don't have to do the Cartesian product yourself.
Then, you can use std::visit to do the job for you:
auto foo(enumA a, enumB b)
-> void (*)(double*, double*, double*)
{
    return std::visit([](auto a, auto b){ return &SomeFunc<a(), b()>; },
                      to_variant(a), to_variant(b));
}
// or directly
void foo(enumA a, enumB b, double* x, double* y, double* z)
{
    std::visit([&](auto a, auto b){ return SomeFunc<a(), b()>(x, y, z); },
               to_variant(a), to_variant(b));
}

Note: I used enum instead of int here, as it better expresses than possible values are "limited", but you can do it with int if you prefer.

Perhaps you could make use of a table of function pointers, like this:
#include <iostream>

typedef double (*SomeFunc)(double*, double*, double*);

template<int a, int b>
auto f1(double* x, double* y, double* z) {
    return a + b + *x + *y + *z;
}

SomeFunc table[] = {
    f1<1, 1>,
    f1<1, 2>,
    f1<2, 1>,
    f1<2, 2>,
};

auto DecideFuncPtr(int A, int B) {
    return table[(A-1)*2 + B-1];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    double x = 1, y = 3, z = 5;
    
    for (int a = 1; a < 3; ++a)
        for (int b = 1; b < 3; ++b)
            std::cout << DecideFuncPtr(a, b)(&x, &y, &z) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}


I forgot to explicitly define the function type SomeFunc. It is void not double. Anyway, I think you're approach might be slightly better, as it involves grouping all the ugly syntax in the table[]. Thanks

Assuming that your desired range of as and bs are contiguous, or you don't mind having the holes instantiated, you can construct a (2d) array of function pointers, and then index into it at runtime.
auto DecideFuncPtr(int A, int B) {
    static constexpr auto FuncPtrs = [=]<int... Xs>(std::integer_sequence<int, Xs...>) {
        return std::array{
        [=]<int X, int...Ys>(std::integral_constant<int, X>, std::integer_sequence<int, Ys...>) {
            return std::array<FuncPtr, MaxB - MinB>{ &SomeFunc<MinA + X, MinB + Ys>... };
        }(std::integral_constant<int, Xs>(), std::make_integer_sequence<int, MaxB - MinB>())... };
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<int, MaxA - MinA>());

    return FuncPtrs[A - MinA][B - MinB];
}

If you are fine with 0s, then you don't need MinA and MinB
Coliru link
Alternately, if the values are all over the place, having the lookup be a map might be better.
constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 5, 9, 42> As;
constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 4, 18, 21, 69> Bs;

auto DecideFuncPtr(int A, int B) {
    static const auto FuncPtrs = [=]<int... Xs>(std::integer_sequence<int, Xs...>) {
        std::map<std::pair<int, int>, FuncPtr> result;
        (result.merge([=]<int X, int...Ys>(std::integral_constant<int, X>, std::integer_sequence<int, Ys...>) {
            return std::map<std::pair<int, int>, FuncPtr>{ { {X, Ys}, &SomeFunc<X, Ys> }... };
        }(std::integral_constant<int, Xs>(), Bs)), ...);
        return result;
    }(As);

    return FuncPtrs.at({A, B});
}

Where the numbers in the types of As and Bs are the values you have.
Coliru link

The contiguous values in a and b is just for demonstration. They're not necessarily contiguous. That said, I think I would have to spend the rest of the day tying to decipher what you did here (I mean it in a nice way).

@debronee101 the innermost lambda creates a std::array<FuncPtr, NumB> by pack-expanding 0, 1, ... NumB-1, which is created by std::make_integer_sequence. Wrapped around that is another expansion for the As. For completely discontinuous values you might use std::map<int, FuncPtr>, which you could fill out in a similar way
